# Can GCP Pub/Sub be used for a webhook? No, because of domain validation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to build a webhook into my app. More precisely, I want a user to be able to set a HTTP POST URL into my app UI, and when events occur, I want my app to send data to this endpoint. Keep in mind that the endpoint is not my domain (it could be `google.com/endpoint` or `example.com/endpoint`...

I use GCP and [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) seems to be the perfect choice. My app publishes events and Pub/Sub handles everything: try to post my data to endpoint, retry if failure, autoscaling...

The problem is that, according to Pub/Sub [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push), I need to validate the domain I send data to (!!). But this domain is not mine, it's the user domain...

So my questions are:

- Am I totally misunderstanding something about Pub/Sub ?
- If I MUST validate user domain (something I can't do), then Pub/Sub is not the right product for my webhook: but which one is in GCP?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find this article on [WebPay's webhook delivery](https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/learnings-about-pubsub-and-ipn) using GCP Pub/Sub an interesting read. Seems it is close to what you might be trying to do. Clearly you can't use Pub/Sub to directly make HTTP POST calls to your client's webhook receiving endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior of Pub/Sub as it's mentioned on the documentation you have linked

In this case, you could use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-python) by Pub/sub. A Cloud Function is a simple way to run a piece of code for a short period of time.

This means that once you trigger the Pub/Sub message, this will trigger a Cloud Function which can get all the data contained in the message and post the data to any domain.

Cloud Functions automatically scales and you pay only when the code is run.

**Important:** Cloud Functions acknowledges internally the message received after the function has finished executing and is successful. There is a document for [retrying](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) functions.

Comment: This is the proper suggestion.  I would only add that you should throw an error from your cloud function if your http request is unsuccessful to nack.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, but the Google doc says [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) you can have it now without any domain proof.

[image]

which means you no longer need to have an intermediate HTTPS Proccesser.

Note: if the subscriber is not Acknowledging, the retry system will send duplicates and make sure about ordering(Pub/Sub supports).